# rich:fileUpload without upload button

Tags: richfaces

I'm using RichFaces 4.2.2 and I'd like to know if is there any way to implement a rich:fileUpload without the upload button?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
[RichFaces Migration Guide. 3.3.x - 4.x Migration](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-ComponentsMigration-RichInputComponents)
It states that auto upload is not yet implemented (it used to work in 3.3.x)